# No coverage in IDE, but coveragepy shows 46% coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, coverage.py

I'm trying to get code coverage metrics in my IDE, but I can't seem to get the coverage to show right.  It always shows up as no coverage.

I am using the following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/ale.vim`:

```
Plug 'mgedmin/coverage-highlight.vim'
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim'
Plug 'prabirshrestha/vim-lsp'
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
call plug#end()
```

I can clone my github project and run tests.  My [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/) report shows 46% coverage:

```
$ coverage report
Name                                           Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/dwenjii/pmlib/pmlib/__init__.py       0      0   100%
/home/dwenjii/pmlib/pmlib/task.py         154     92    40%
test_pmlib.py                                     16      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                            170     92    46%
```

As you can see, that's 46% coverage, but `mgedmin/coverage-highlight.vim` shows no red when I execute `:HighlightCoverage`.

I have the following versions:

```
attrs == 23.1.0
loguru == 0.7.2
tasklib == 2.5.1
texttable == 1.7.0
matplotlib == 3.8.2
coverage == 7.3.2
pytest == 7.4.3
```

How do I fix this problem so I show the real uncovered lines in my IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your `.coverage` sqllite coverage report is not in your base git directory.  In this case, it's in `/home/dwenjii/pmlib/tests/.coverage`, but it needs to be in `/home/dwenjii/pmlib/.coverage`.

If you don't have `.coverage` in your base git directory, then `mgedmin/coverage-highlight.vim` won't see any coverage metrics (even if `.coverage` is in `tests/`).

Comment: that fixed the problem, now I see uncovered lines in vim ide